# Floor heating is not as warm as I was expected

Tags: heating, floorheating

I've just moved in a one-room flat which has floor heating. I thought that floor heating would be enough but it turns out to be a disaster. The room is not heating as a normal room with a radiator. I can only feel the heat coming from the pipes which are located under on several places. Is this normal with floor heating or is there something wrong with my flat? The constructor of the house came and checked and told me that everything is as it is supposed to be.

What should I do to make the flat warmer?

Missing information: 
You can control the temperature with a thermostat, which is maximum 30 celcius degrees. Outside is approx. 0 degrees. The floor is parquet. I have no knowledge about pipe layout though. The floor is not uniformly warm but only specific parts of the floor.

**A little update:** Today, they issued a mail to all of the occupants regarding the heating system is broken and they'll have to fix it. When I asked them to check if it is broken, they told me that it was working just the way it should be. Anyways, thanks for all the  help, it had already begun to get warmer when I started to keep it open all the time, let's see what will happen after they fix it.

Comment: More detail, please. You haven't given us much to go on. Floor construction? Heat system type? Pipe layout and type? Please revise your post with this information.

Comment: Please add more details to make this answerable, such as: Do you have a thermostat or something else to control the heating with? What's the current and desired inside temperature and the outside temperature? The whole floor should be more or less uniformly warm. Do you mean that it isn't?

Comment: Yes, you can control the temperature with a termostat, which is maximum 30 celcius degrees. Outside is approx. 0 degrees. The floor is parquet. I have no knowledge about pipe layout though. @TooTea, no it is not uniformly warm but only specific parts of the floor.

Comment: Radiant heat takes time. I have installed a system with a small boiler that actually took 3 days to achieve the desired temp (insulated concrete slab) Once the temp is achieved it is very efficient. Keeping the thermostat at a constant temp will be important.

Comment: What does a thermometer say? What is the thermostat set to, and how long has it been set there? These are high mass systems, so they take time to stabilize. In general, if the floor felt "toasty" the temperature would be absurdly high, unless the building is **very** poorly insulated. The floor only needs to be warm enough to keep the set temperature, and that will typically be below body temperature, so still "cool" to skin.

Comment: Do you know if the pipes are embedded in concrete or a "fin style" system?  There are several ways of installing radiant.  I have radiant in concrete and like Ed Beal said, it's slow.  Due to that, it also doesn't work well with programmable thermostats if they are programmed for a lot of setback if you are "away" or at night. Radiant is just too slow.  I run most of my house with NO SETBACK.  Depending upon the system, there might be a lot of other adjustments, IE Supply temp, outdoor reset (adjusting supply temp based on outdoor temp), cycle time... and lots more.

Comment: _"you can control the temperature with a termostat..."_ -- please do not use the comments to clarify your question. The comments are for the rest of us to request clarifications. You need to [edit your question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/183067/edit) to improve it based on the comments provided.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson my no setback, do you mean you do not turn off the thermostat at all? Wouldn't that cause a huge bill?

Comment: @PeterDuniho sorry for that, I've edited the original question

Comment: Regarding "huge bill":  That all depends upon how well insulated your apartment is and now much additional usage there will be.  You might try it for a while for a couple of reasons:  1) See how much it costs when you get the bill and 2)  see if it can actually heat up your place to set point.  The bottom line is you are stuck with a slow heating system. It's nice, I love radiant, but it's slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Floor heating systems are **very slow and normally meant to run 24/7** except for long-term absence (> 3 days), if the building hull is insulated to some extent or if it is a huge building with high volume-to-surface ratio.

Do the **neighbours** have the same problem? Which floor is it?
How many outside walls does this flat have? What is below the floor, what is above the ceiling?
Any valves besides thermostats in the flat?

The warm pads could be caused by domestic hot water (circulation) lines.

Reasons for underperforming:

- In **new buildings**, much energy is needed to dry the walls, floors and ceilings.
- In older systems, **clogging** could be the problem since the tube material (plastic) allowed for oxygen and other gases to diffuse into the system increasing corrosion at the metal parts. Also bypass valves can be blocked (not closing ⟶ more or less heating water is bypassing the room) by tiny rust parts.
- There could be **valves** for each room (in this case for each apartment), near the heating system or somewhere hidden, which are meant to adjust the **throughput** which might be different e.g. due to unequal tube/hose loop lengths. These valves are different from thermostat valves and could be de-adjusted.
- **Incorrect settings** or design of the heating system, or not enough maintenance, especially with heat pumps. Heating water temperature too low, pump power too low, incorrect location for outside temperature sensor (on sunny south side instead of north), restrictions by timers etc.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the clarification. It's on the second floor. And it is a new building, I am one of the first residents. There is one door and two from ceeling to the floor windows. I was not aware of it was supposed to be on all the time. I will try to let it run for 24/7 as soon as I get home.

Comment: @huckfin Some owners/landlords like to "outsource" the costs for drying the building to the first tenants right after finishing construction. 
The other flats should have the heating switched on, even if they are still empty. It may take months or even a year until all the redundant water has left the building material. For buildings with concrete the needed energy and time could be huge.
A fair owner would share a part of the heating costs for the according time. Anyway the moisture inside the concrete should be measured/logged.

Comment: so, I should, maybe, talk with the owner and suggest them to share the costs if keeping the thermostat on all the time won't work, right?

Comment: @huckfin Maybe the 1st step would be to inform the owner about the important fact that a new (concrete) building must be dryed, otherwise huge damage and high costs may result. Among all causes for building damages, incorrect drying is one of the most frequent.  
All flats' heating must be on - and not only set to anti-freeze. This will help your flat to get warmer, of course.